# Fontify headline with todo keyword color

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, todo

I would like to fontify headlines with the same color/weight as their TODO keywords. So for example, the default is like this:

**TODO** Headline

And I want it to look like this:

**TODO Headline**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what face is applied to the text under point (the cursor) with the command `M-x describe-face`.

By doing this, I learned that the face applied to `TODO` keywords is called `org-todo`. The Face for top-level headings is `org-level-1`.

You can customize faces using via `M-x customize-face`. You can set attributes individually, or you can apply the attributes from one face directly to another using the **Inherit** attribute. In your case, set the **Inherit** attribute for `org-level-1` to `org-todo`.

When you're done, `C-c C-c` in the customize buffer will set your changes temporarily, and `C-c C-s` will save them permanently.

Answer (score 1):

For DONE-keywords, there is a variable `org-fontify-done-headline` that activates fontification of the whole headline. To do this also for "not-done" keywords, we have to add a similar extra font-lock rule for org. The easiest way to do this is by modifying `org-font-lock-extra-keywords` using `org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook` (this then runs when initializing each buffer, as TODO-keywords etc. can vary).
The following works for the case of fontifying “not-done” headlines:

```
(defface aj/org-headline-todo '((t :inherit org-todo :weight normal))
  "Face for TODO headlines."
  :group 'org-faces)

(defun aj/org-fontify-todo-headlines ()
  "Add rule for fontifying not-done headlines in org-mode."
  (push (list (format org-heading-keyword-regexp-format org-not-done-regexp)
              '(2 'aj/org-headline-todo t))
        org-font-lock-extra-keywords))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook #'aj/org-fontify-todo-headlines)
```

The custom face that inherits from `org-todo` can of course be customized to suit your needs.